# setStoreId() not working on quote collecton

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, quote, store-id

I have been loading quote collection like this:

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')
                        ->setStoreId($store)
                        ->load($quote_id);
```

I have 2 stores on my website. Above code gives same result on my both stores. ie: `setStoreId` is not working here.

How do i get store wise `quote` ?

Comment: Why to set store ID if you load the quote by unique ID?

Comment: @sv3n  you cannot load quote without setting the storeid. So that i have to set the store_id. if you load quote without store_id you will get error like this

`{
    "messages": {
        "error": [
            {
                "code": 400,
                "message": "No items in shopping cart"
            }
        ]
    }
}`

Comment: @passion : if you look in the `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote` class, you will find a method `loadByIdWithoutStore`. Maybe you can give it a try.

Comment: @passion have you entered a valid quote ID? Havent digged deeper yet, but I can load quotes w/o store ID - but for some I get an empty result?

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like :

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->getCollection()
                                      ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',$quoteId);
                                      ->addFieldToFilter('store_id', $storeId)
                                      ->setPageSize(1)
                                      ->getFirstItem();
```